# Showing loading spinner while fetching the local data

Tags: angular, typescript, spinner, loading

I am having difficulties understanding the following:

I have an Image object:

```
export class Image {
  id: string;
  imageName: string;
  imageDesc: string;
  base64?: string;  // optional for future converting
}
```

I then define an array of objects:

```
export const mockImages: Image[] = [
  {
    id: 'image1',
    imageName: 'image1.jpg',
    imageDesc: 'Description of the first picture.',
  },
  {
    id: 'image2',
    imageName: 'image2.jpg',
    imageDesc: 'Description of the second picture.',
  },
  {
    id: 'image3',
    imageName: 'image3.jpg',
    imageDesc: 'Description of the third picture.',
  }
]
```

In the ts file I load the data and also start the conversion

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.imageData = mockImages;
    this.myService.convertImg();
  }
```

In my html, I loop through this data, and while they don´t have specified the fourth parameter base64, I want to conditionaly show loading spinner instead of the image:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of imageData; let i = index">
  <div [hidden]="!data[i]?.base64">
     <img
        (click)="onPreviewImage(i)"
        [src]="data.base64"
        [alt]="data.imageDesc"
     />
   </div>
   <app-loading-tab [hidden]="data[i]?.base64"></app-loading-tab>
</div>
```

convertImg() function in the myService. I am also defining the mockImages and mockImagesPath property.

```
convertImg(): void {
    const numberOfFiles = this.mockImages.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
      this.http
        .get(`${this.mockImagesPath}/${this.mockImages[i].imageName}`, {responseType: 'blob'})
        .subscribe((res) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.mockImages[i].base64 = reader.result as string;
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(res);
        });
    }
  }
```

But this approach is not doing what I would expect - which is conditionally show and hide loader while data is being loaded / and is already displayed. I always see the loading spinners as if the conversion was not recognized.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What I think is going on here is that the state for the `imageData` array that you're displaying in your HTML isn't being updated when converting the images. In order to verify this, you can `console.log(imageData)` before and after converting, to check whether the required `base64` is being updated or not.

If this is the case, then I'd add a response to the `convertImg` method, to return the new array that has the `base64` converted data and use the returned array to update the `imageData` array.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this. Console logging this.mockImages before the conversion and after the loop (the conversion) in service returns data without base64, even though the conversion and push to the array happened inside the loop.

Comment: ok so when I assign this new array to the this.imageData, how do I manage conditions between showing either loading spinner or image? this.imageData in this case will always have base64 values

Comment: And although the property this.imageData contains value for base64, I still see loading spinner instead of image.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a Subject on your service class, something like

```
public imageConverted = new Subject<Image>();
```

Then in your convert method, notify whenever an image is done converting:

```
convertImg(): void {
    const numberOfFiles = this.mockImages.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
      this.http
        .get(`${this.mockImagesPath}/${this.mockImages[i].imageName}`, {responseType: 'blob'})
        .subscribe((res) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.mockImages[i].base64 = reader.result as string;
            this.imageConverted.next(this.mockImages[i]);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(res);
          
        });
    }
  }
```

Finally in your component subscribe to the event and update the image that's done converting:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.imageData = mockImages;
    this.myService.imageConverted.subscribe({
        next: (image) => {
            const index = this.imageData.findIndex(i => i.id === image.id);
            if (index > -1) {
               this.imageData[index] = image;
            }
        }
    });
    this.myService.convertImg();
  }
```

Comment: hi @Csaba. Thank you but after updating the code there is still only loading spinner visible. Am I missing something in my html?

Comment: ohh, my mistake. I should have data?.base64 instead of data[i]?.base64